# Selenium webdriver page_source not giving whole content after scrolled_down

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a twitter site, There are a long list of comments so using selenium I scrolled down till the end:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
for i in range(30):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Now when I try to get elements by tag name, **article** all the tags aren't captured.

```
> len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article'))
16
```

When I scroll the page manually and try the same code

```
> len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article'))
20
```

Same is the case for page_source. When I save the `driver.page_source` to a file, and open that file to search existing twitter username, *the name is not found*. Only the usernames at the end of html are present.

First, I thought it might have been browser issue. Then I tried same thing with ChromeDriver. But the results were similar.

Comment: Is it possible to show the url of the page?

Comment: Here you go `https://twitter.com/OnePlus_NPL/status/1273912248633704448`

Comment: Did you try changing 30  to number greater than 30?

Comment: Well the issue is not with the number 30. Its actually 30 times scrolled down! I have scrolled in twice; First range(20) , then range(10) until I reach point of no-scroll